# are there any solution when I calculate all elements from array?

Tags: ruby

everyone!

I would like to calculate all income in $incomes.
As you can see, first array's income is 10 ,second one is 20, third one is 30.
and I would like to calculate all of them.

When I tried to solve this, it always showed "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" in console. 
Then, I put .to_i or .to_s, but it did not work.

Are there any solution for it? Thank you.

```
$incomes = [
    { companyID: 0, income: 10 ,description: "jun invoice", date: "2019/08/08"},
    { companyID: 0, income: 20 ,description: "aug invoice", date: "2019/09/08"},
    { companyID: 0, income: 30 ,description: "sep invoice", date: "2019/10/08"}
  ]

def printOurCompanyIncome()
      $incomes.each_with_index do |income, index|
        puts "#{index} -- companyID: #{income[:companyID]}, income: #{income[:income]}, description: #{income[:description]}, date: #{income[:date]}"
      end
end

def computeIncome()
  puts "Calculate all incomes from $incomes here"
end

def smenu()
  puts "0) Print our company income"
  puts "1) Calculate all our company's income "
  decision = gets.chomp
 case decision.to_i
 when 0
   printOurCompanyIncome()
 when 1
   computeIncome()
 else 
    puts "Something went wrong"
  end
end
smenu()
```

Console showed "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer"

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: You link shows that the error occurred in the method `computeIncome` in a second line in the body which is not shown above: `puts "#{$incomes[:income]}"`. `$incomes`, however, is an array, so it expects an integer (for the offset) as its argument. It's argument is a symbol, however, and there's no "implicit conversion of a symbol to an integer".

Comment: It would be easy to give you an answer if you were clear about what is the expected output. Is it an array of numbers? A single number which is the sum?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-sum) to get the sum of all salaries from the hashes nested in your array:

```
$incomes = [
  { companyID: 0, income: 10 ,description: "jun invoice", date: "2019/08/08"},
  { companyID: 0, income: 20 ,description: "aug invoice", date: "2019/09/08"},
  { companyID: 0, income: 30 ,description: "sep invoice", date: "2019/10/08"}
]

def computeIncome()
  puts "Calculate all incomes from $incomes here"
  puts $incomes.sum { |income| income[:income] }
end

computeIncome
#=> Calculate all incomes from $incomes here
#=> 60
```

Btw your code doesn't follow common Ruby styles. For example:

- global variables are almost never used
- method names and variables are written in underscore (not camelcase or Pascal-case)
- No need for empty parentheses
- usually, the code is indented with two spaces

Apart from the first point, these might not be important to have error-free source code but following these conventions and idioms increases readability a lot and makes it much easier to collaborate with other developers. Therefore I advise looking at some well-known style guides, for example, the one from [Rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide).

Comment: Thank you for giving me comment and really useful link!
now i am studying ruby from the beginning! 
i will do my best, thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$incomes = [
  { companyID: 0, income: 10 ,description: "jun invoice", date: "2019/08/08"},
  { companyID: 0, income: 20 ,description: "aug invoice", date: "2019/09/08"},
  { companyID: 0, income: 30 ,description: "sep invoice", date: "2019/10/08"}
].collect{ |income| income[:income] }.sum
```